# Call a method of running java application on the same instance of the application from command prompt

Tags: java

Is there any way to call a certain method in a running java application?

Forexample: I have a java application running, Now I want to call a method `uk.co.planetbeyond.chatservice.Stopper.stop()` on the same instance of the application. Can I do that?

Comment: Did you try to do that first?

Comment: Ya I googled it a lot, but found no answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is using JMX. You just have to expose methods you want to call to MBean. Then you can use any JMX client you want to call the methods. You can either use JConsole that is a part of your JDK or create your own command line application.

There is also [command line JMX client](http://crawler.archive.org/cmdline-jmxclient/).

Answer (score 2):

No.

You could however have your java application:

- listen for input from the command line with `new Scanner(System.in)` (for example)
- listen on a port for input using a variety of protocols, http being a common choice
- watch for appearance of a file (lame, but it would work)

Once running, the JVM will only notice something it's looking for - ie it can only "pull"; you can't "push" anything into it

Comment: Why not? Enable debug, and you'll be perfectly able to stop any thread and call a method in it.

Comment: Yes you can do lots of things via debug. I was answering for the general situation (where debug is not enabled)